# get class variables from nsobject stored in msmutablearray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsobject

I have a class Vehicle which is an NSOBject. It has 4 string variables vrn, make, model, yearmade. I am crating the Vehicle objects from data which i get through a webservice and store each object in an nsmutablearray. How can i access the variables vrn, make, model, yearmade from the mutable array for each stored object?

Edit:
I have tried this:

[[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0];

Edit 2:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //NSLog(@"test");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if ([tableView isEqual:vrnTable]) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            cell.opaque = NO;

            vrnLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60.0, 7.0, 50.0, 30.0)];
            vrnLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
            vrnLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
            vrnLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            vrnLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
            vrnLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            vrnLabel.tag = VRN_LABEL_TAG;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:vrnLabel];

            makeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 7.0, 10.0, 30.0)];
            makeLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
            makeLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
            makeLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            makeLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
            makeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            makeLabel.tag = MAKE_LABEL_TAG;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:makeLabel];

            modelLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200.0, 7.0, 10.0, 30.0)];
            modelLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
            modelLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
            modelLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            modelLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
            modelLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            modelLabel.tag = MODEL_LABEL_TAG;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:modelLabel];

            yearLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120.0, 7.0, 10.0, 30.0)];
            yearLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
            yearLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
            yearLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            yearLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
            yearLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            yearLabel.tag = YEAR_LABEL_TAG;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:yearLabel];
        }
        else {
            vrnLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:VRN_LABEL_TAG];
        }
    }
    NSString *cell_image = [NSString alloc];
    if (indexPath.row != 0) {
        cell_image = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"color%d.png", indexPath.row % 8 + 1];
    }
    else {
        cell_image = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"color%d.png", 0];
    }
    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:cell_image] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];
    vrnLabel.text = ((Vehicle *)[entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).vrn;
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple thing, just use objectAtIndex and use typecast to access object variable:

```
NSString *firstObjVrn = ((Vehicle*)[vehicleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).vrn;
NSString *firstObjMake = ((Vehicle*)[vehicleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).make;
NSString *firstObjModel = ((Vehicle*)[vehicleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).model;
NSString *firstObjYearMade = ((Vehicle*)[vehicleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).yearMade;
```

Comment: I am putting the data on a table cell from each object. doing this is showing same data on each cell

Comment: Your code should fine. It may problem with `entries` array. would you post that array? what error you got?

Comment: array is properly filled. i can see it in NSLog. Problem is that I only see the same data in all tableview cells

Comment: Yes. You are right. Just I want to see that array format. Please post what you saw in log....

Comment: SZC-450 Suzuki Cultus 2005
HCV-780 Honda Civic 2010

Comment: these are two objects

Comment: @HassanZaheer I need that array format. If you post with format like JSON display, it would be easier to analyze. I want to check that entire array format whether nested array or array contain other format object.

Comment: Now also vrnLabel have same value for all cell?

Comment: [{SZC-450, Suzuki, Cultus, 2005}, {HCV-780, Honda, Civic, 2010}]
Square brackets represent the array and curly brackets represent the vehicle object

Comment: In your tableview, what about section count ?

Comment: 140. which is absolutely right. there are 140 objects in the array

Comment: then this is problem. If you use section count as array count means, you have replace `indexPath.row` by `indexPath.section`.